# Duplicate Docker image in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, scaling, aws-cli

Let’s say I have a docker image that does some work. I want to create 100 instances of that image in AWS, only controls I need is to specify how many instances I need per region. There are no tricky configs or anything, I just want to run the same app 100 times.

Is there a simple solution, or do I have to look into swarm/kubernities?

Comment: On how many compute nodes?  Do they need to communicate with each other or share state in any way?

Comment: Application is standalone. Instances should not be aware of each other. Because there is quite a lot of port forwarding between host and image, optimum is to have one image instance per host

Comment: You might look at tools like Terraform or CloudFormation to spin up a bunch of identical EC2 instances.  You might be able to specify the startup information in a userdata script, or you might need to build a custom AMI that runs the container on startup (maybe using Packer).  As you're describing the problem you're just using Docker as a way to package the software, and it's not otherwise different from "I need to launch 100 identical EC2 instances".

Comment: Thank you, I agree. I was just curious if there is an AWS service that can take a Dockerfile and deploy it automatically on ‘n’ instances

Comment: ECS is possibly closest, but if you're especially concerned about 1 container per instance it's not necessarily a great match.